# while statement

Tags: python-2.7

```
def sequence(n):
    while n != 1:
        print n,
        if n%2 == 0:        # n is even
           n = n/2
      else:               # n is odd
            n = n*3+1


sequence(6)
6 3 10 5 16 8 4 2
```

Why the output doesn't include 1 here?Many many thanx!

Comment: Because while loop breaks on n != 1 condition.

Answer (score 1):

try using `<=` or `>=` for instance, `while n >= 1`. That should do what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

You have the while loop set on breaking if `n == 1`. Try possibly doing `n > 0` or `n >= 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while n != 1:
       print n
```

Once n gets a value of 1, it won't enter the loop, thus not allowing 'n' to be printed.

Comment: Yea, I just realised != means not equal in python, not factorial...Many thanx for your answer!